# How to set up a debugger for a Chrome (or Edge) extension to properly breakpoint source files served outside of wwwroot?

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge, chromium

My project is laid out as so:

```
${workspaceFolder}
  /wwwroot
  /res
```

The /res directory is for serving files through a secure controller.

My issue is when it comes to source debugging in VS Code via the "Debugger for Chrome" (or Edge) extensions.

If I put a breakpoint in a JS file in VS Code, it will work properly if the file exists under the wwwroot directory (it stops at that point in the source).

But if the js file is served from the /res directory (to /res in the web browser), VS Code will open up a new instance of that file, rather than the source instance.

I think I need to do some kind of directory mapping for the debugger to translate http://localhost/res to ${workspaceFolder}/res for debugging the source files, but am unsure of the proper setup (possibly needing to set sourceMapPathOverrides, but my attempts have failed.).

Comment: The debugger uses sourcemaps to let you debug with your original sources, but sometimes the sourcemaps aren't generated properly and overrides are needed. In the config we support sourceMapPathOverrides, a mapping of source paths from the sourcemap, to the locations of these sources on disk. Useful when the sourcemap isn't accurate or can't be fixed in the build process. Ref: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/debugger-for-edge

Comment: I am aware of the source map overrides, and have attempted to use the command (as stated in my question) to no avail. The almost complete lack of syntax and variable documentation along with poorly explained examples not pertaining to standard routing is confusing.  I've tried     "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "/res/*": "${workspaceFolder}/res/*"
            }

Comment: I suggest you create issue on their github repo. Ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-edge-debug2/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong command.  **pathMapping** is what I needed to use.

The launch.json configuration below allows me to breakpoint source files located outside of wwwroot (in this case, /res)

```
{
    "name": "Launch localhost in Microsoft Edge (Chromium) Canary",
    "type": "edge",
    "request": "launch",
    "version": "canary",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5100/test.html",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/wwwroot",
    "pathMapping": {
        "/res": "${workspaceFolder}/res"
    }
}
```